# Trackpad not working on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

On my MacBook Pro, my trackpad isn't working. The mouse won't move, so I cannot turn off the Mac. Already tried a shut down and it doesn't work. I can't do anything on this computer without my mouse. How can I fix this? Mouse buttons won't work either.

Comment: Please do not edit the OP with thing like "Problem fixed", and instead you can answer your own question, as this will help others better when they encounter the same issue and there is a clearly defined issue and a clearly defined answer.  Anyway based on your edit(s) it's not totally clear whether or not you've resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can try:

- Check your trackpad setting (Use Spotlight [⌘ + Space] to open System Preferences and use the tab and arrow keys to navigate through the options)
- Try the options listed in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151907/how-to-bring-back-multi-touch-gestures-after-it-crashes-without-reboot)
- Plug in a USB mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any response from the Keyboard and or Trackpad you can always hold down the power button until it turns off.  It's not the best solution however if you have no other options then its a way to go.