# What is "hidd"?

Tags: macos, daemons

I tried to find some details about the daemon `hidd` but only found information about a Linux daemon where it is the human interface device daemon.

Is this the same function in macOS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## What is `hidd` responsible for?

`hidd` is indeed an abbreviation for Human Interface Device Daemon. It is responsible for the operation of any human input devices, such as your mouse, trackpad, drawing tablet or keyboard.

#### High CPU or memory utilisation?

If you are experiencing high CPU or memory utilization from hidd, you may want to restart your computer.

#### Can I kill the process?

No, if the hidd process is killed, it will restart immediately.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is restarted with high CPU as well? Or whether there is another solution than to restart your computer? (There has to be!)